# LibVLCSharp record while streaming

Tags: c#, record, libvlcsharp

I am trying to implement a record button into my LibVLC rtsp stream. The recording works but when i try to record it it only records the RTSP stream for 3 seconds and when it does the recording the stream stops completely. How do I make it stream continuously while recording the RTSP stream? The code is below. I'm still learning C# so please give me a chance!

```cs
void RecordButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{       
    var currentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
    var destination = Path.Combine(currentDirectory, "record.mp4");

    rtsp1.AddOption(":screen-fps=24");
    rtsp1.AddOption(":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=0,scale=0,acodec=mp4a,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:file{dst=record1.mp4}");
    rtsp1.AddOption(":sout-keep");

    VideoView2.MediaPlayer.Play(rtsp1); // start recording

    //await Task.Delay(5000); // record for 5 seconds
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    VideoView2.MediaPlayer.Stop(); // stop recording and saves the file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While you could do that with the VLC app itself, it belongs to one of the few things that are not yet available to the libvlc API, and thus not available to LibVLCSharp.

VLC uses internal APIs of libvlccore to add/remove streaming outputs (sout).

You would need two players for that, or use another library.

Comment: so to clarify cube45's answer, it is technically possible, though not optimal, because you need to use 2 mediaplayers objects (one for playback, one for recording).

Comment: Is there any reference that I can seek for help from? I'm really weak at coding and would need guidance to get things done

Comment: here's an example with multiple mediaplayers https://code.videolan.org/mfkl/libvlcsharp-samples/-/tree/master/VideoMosaic